# Loading different video (html5) quality according to screen resolution

Tags: javascript, html, video, screen, resolution

Im trying to display different video resolution according to the users screen height resolution, i have this code but im not an expert with javascript.  It's supposed to change the src attribute, if the res is lower o equal to 360px height, and so on.
Any suggestions?

```js
<script type="text/rocketscript">
var v = new Array();
v[0] = ["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51626189/nli-vids/intro/intro-360_x264.mp4"];

v[1] = ["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51626189/nli-vids/intro/intro-480_x264.mp4"];

v[2] = ["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51626189/nli-vids/intro/intro-720_x264.mp4"];

v[3] = ["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51626189/nli-vids/intro/intro-1080_x264.mp4"];
function changeVid(n){
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
if (screen.height<=360) {video.setAttribute("src", v[n][0]);}
else if (screen.height<=480) {video.setAttribute("src", v[n][1]);}
else if (screen.height<=720) {video.setAttribute("src", v[n][2]);}
else if (screen.height<=768) {video.setAttribute("src", v[n][2]);}
else if (screen.height<=1080) {video.setAttribute("src", v[n][3]);}
else if (screen.width>=1920) {video.setAttribute("src", v[n][3]);}
video.load();}
</script>
```

```html
<video id="video" autoplay preload src="#">
</video>
```

Comment: You should ask a more specific question or describe a more specific problem you’re having. Does the code work? Does something unexpected happen when you run it? What kind of suggestions are you looking for?

Comment: well, the code did not work, it's supposed to change the src attribute, if the res is lower o equal to 360px height, and so on.

Comment: So you should probably update your question to include that information. You probably don’t want to assume that anybody’s going to take time to run the code themselves to find out where it fails.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about "text/rocketscript" (something to do with Wordpress and/or CloudFlare?), but this Javascript works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var v = new Array();
v[0] = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51626189/nli-vids/intro/intro-360_x264.mp4";
v[1] = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51626189/nli-vids/intro/intro-480_x264.mp4";
v[2] = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51626189/nli-vids/intro/intro-720_x264.mp4";
v[3] = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51626189/nli-vids/intro/intro-1080_x264.mp4";

function changeVid() {
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    if (screen.height <= 360) video.setAttribute("src", v[0]);
    else if (screen.height <= 480) video.setAttribute("src", v[1]);
    else if (screen.height <= 768) video.setAttribute("src", v[2]);
    else video.setAttribute("src", v[3]);

    video.load();
}

changeVid();
</script>
```

Sorry, I can't get it to work as a snippet, JS Fiddle here instead: http://jsfiddle.net/3g59yomb/

Note that it loads a high-res video (on my system with a 2560 x 1440 screen) even though my browser window is much smaller, and the JS Fiddle frame even smaller still. That may or may not be a bug!  But it does load a video.

Comment: Great, glad to help! If it's working for you now please consider accepting my answer, thanks.