# Try to put one video for desktop and other for mobile and tablet

Tags: html, css, web

Hi I tried to put one video for medium or lower devices and a different video for laptops and desktops and I can’t figure out how to do it

[image]

that’s what I tried to do, if anyone can help me I’ll be very grateful! Thank you all

Comment: In the first line, the brackets aren't closed behind your pixel value. Please also share the code with us, so we can help you more easily.

Comment: `media` should only be used on `<picture>`. Try using separate CSS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source#attr-media

Comment: Also try to learn how to make print screens instead of taking photos of your display :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading different video (html5) quality according to screen resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954262/loading-different-video-html5-quality-according-to-screen-resolution)

Answer (score 2):

You may use javascript for this.

For example, let's say the layout is like this.

```
<video src="" id="my-video">
  <source src="" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
```

You may try to get the video element and then compute the window size to dynamically generate the video source.

```
const video = document.getElementById("my-video")

const screenWidth = window.innerWidth
const isMobile = screenWidth<=600

console.log(video.querySelector("source").src)
video.querySelector("source").src = isMobile?"https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/compileonline.mp4":"https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use css `@media` queries to hide a the other video depending on screen size.